# Save to database from multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Android app i have an Activity with tabs and each tab changes to a different Fragment, each with several fields the user should fill. The user can then submit all data by clicking a button in the action bar.

Is there an easy way to access and store all data from the different Fragments at action bar button click? Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem right, I'd see two possible solutions:

1) To copy the data from the fragments to a class extending the `Application` class, so that class work as a placeholder for global variables. You only would need to capture the input events on the fragments to update the class, or to capture the fragment transition to copy the data from it to the Application

2) You can inflate your fragments' views into the main activity one by setting the `attachToRoot` flag. Then it should be possible to find them with `findViewById` in the main activity

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear on what you mean by save. If you want to store the data locally on the phone:
[Android Storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)
From these I strongly recommend SQLite for more complex data and Shared Preferences for simple (String or int) type data.

Comment: Yes, i mean store in an SQLite database. The question is, how? How do i access the different fragment fields and their values so i can store them, since the user is moving from fragment to fragment and in the end clicks the actionbar to persist?

Answer (score 0):

When You Entering the data in First Fragment that all data you can store it into one String by comma separated value and then access that values into second fragment and split that string and store it into Sqlite DB .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to save data to your database from various parts of your app. I would suggest you use ContentProvider/ContentResolver for this. With this approach you would implement a ContentProvider which interacts with your database and from anywhere else in the app you would use a ContentResolver to interact with the ContentProvider.

In your ContentProvider you would have to implement the methods, query(), insert(), delete(), update(), onCreate() and getType(). Uris are used to identify what you want to insert or select from the ContentProvider. You can use a static UriMatcher to make parsing of the Uris very simple. I will give you an example on how to implement the query method with a sqlite database:

This is how you would define an UriMatcher in your Provider:

```
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    // Here you define your Uris, in this case for a table I called TABLE_ONE.
    // If you want to know what each of these parameters means I suggest you view the documentation
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, TABLE_ONE_ID);
}

// I suggest you define all constants like the AUTHORITY and BASEPATH and Uri's in a Contract class.
// You create the Uris from the value of AUTHORITY and BASE_PATH like this:
public static final Uri TABLE_ONE_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH);
```

And this is a rudimentary implementation of the query method:

```
public Cursor query (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Cursor c = null;

    // The UriMatcher gives you the id of the uri if you added it like in the above example
    int uriId = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriId ) {
        case TABLE_ONE_ID:
            SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
            c = db.query(TABLE_ONE_NAME, projecton, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
            c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }

    return c;
}
```

And then in your app you can select data from the db using a ContentResolver like this:

```
// Note that getContentResolver is a method of Activity, in a Fragment you have to call getActivity().getContentResolver()
getContentResolver().query(TABLE_ONE_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

Here is the link to a complete Tutorial about pretty much anything important regarding SQLite and ContentProviders in Android:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html
Here you can find the official guide from Google on how to implement a ContentProvider:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html